# Load an external textfile into a Visual studio 2012 ListView (Windows store)

Tags: c#, windows, listview, visual-studio-2012

I have recently been trying to load an external textfile, called `KS1words.txt` into a listview in Visual Studio 2012 windows store blank page, upon entering the page with the listviews. The code worked 1 day ago, but there was an error with loading files which I could not fix, so I created a new programme with the same things, and the same code that worked, now does not, I have attached it here and there is also a screenshot with the page with the `ListViews`. Do you have any idea what might the cause of the problem be ?
I am running this on a virtual machine !
Thank you

[image: Screenshot]

CODE:

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FillList(@"Assets\KS1words.txt");
    }
    async private void FillList(string filename)
    {
        var KS1wordlist= new List<String>();
        // this method reads line separated words from a text file and populates a List object // 
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        // begin the file read operation 
        try
        {
            // open and read in the word list into an object called words 

            StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            var KS1wordsvar= await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(sampleFile);
            // add each word returned to a list of words declared 
            // globally as List wordList = new List();
            foreach (var word in KS1wordsvar) { KS1wordlist.Add(word); }
            List1.ItemsSource = KS1wordlist;
        }
        catch (Exception) { 
            // handle any errors with reading the file
        }
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what is "not working". Are you getting an error message? If the file is under "Assets" then you have to make sure that the file (in the properties tab) is set to "copy to output". That will ensure that the file will get copied to the output directory.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant is, the program runs successfully with no errors, but in the end, it does not show anything in the listview..and yes the textfiles were not in the project, but i added them to the exact page where i am trying to implement them and the result is still the same

Comment: And, yes, it is set to always copy to output

Comment: Well I put together a sample project and your code seems to work for me. Did you by chance hook up the `Loaded` event to your `Page_Loaded` function? In other words you could do something like the following in your page constructor: `this.Loaded += Page_Loaded;`

Comment: I am afraid this did not work as well. I am sure that the code is correct, but i feel there is something really small missing somewhere that causes the whole thing not to work

Answer (score 0):

since you are using

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
```

to get the folder , make sure that your text file is in the right directory.

Comment: Yes, my file is in the same folder, where the programming files are